# How can I prevent myself from powering down my phone while "Alarmy (Sleep If U Can)" is trying to wake me up?

Tags: alarm, shutdown

How can I make the phone impossible to turn off. I use an alarm clock which make a task I must complete before the ringing alarm turns off.

My problem is that I can simply turn off the phone and then I don't need to complete any task for the alarm to go away. So my question is that can I in some way make the phone impossible to turn off when the alarm is ringing? So then I would be forced to make the tasks(math problems, barcode scanner...) before I can turn off the phone.

Any idea is highly appreciated and If you know some app that will do this or if I can do this by rooting my phone so let me know. No solution is to hard for me, I will try anything suggested.

Comment: The power button is hardware.  You're not going to find an app to prevent the button from being pressable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw that they updated Alarmy (Sleep If U Can) to ver.7.3 on the 3rd of january with a new option called Preventing phone switch off. I wounder where they read about this idea;)

Answer (score -2):

There is an app called [Alarm Clock Xtreme](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alarmclock.xtreme.free&hl=en) on the Play Store. I used it a year ago and it worked great, but I tried it a month ago and it was draining my battery. Try it out and see if it works for you.

Comment: I tried that app and I Can't Wake Up. But this app doesn't solve my problem they are just alarm clock apps(not that they are bad on what they do) but they don't block me from shutting of my phone which is the problem. I think you need to read my post again or ask me if that I wrote was unclear.