# Is there some way to prevent myself from shutting down my [rooted] phone in some specific cases?

Tags: root-access, magisk, termux, shutdown, google-pixel-6

This is question is basically an acknowledgement that I'm very f-ing lazy.

First, I'm on a Pixel 6 Pro running stock A13, rooted and filled with Magisk modules.

I needed to find a way to guarantee I'll wake up, so I tried [Alarmy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=droom.sleepIfUCan) (I just noticed the apk id is droom.**sleepIfUCan**, haha), which has a really cool feature of posing a few physical and/or mental challenges to stop the alarm from ringing.

But well, the very first day I tried it (with no real need to wake up at the time I set), I didn't feel like waking up, as I had nothing scheduled, so I simply turned my phone off (I'm not sure, but I think Alarmy blocked my screen and stopped me from pulling the dropdown menu or switching to other apps, so I used the Power+Vol Up menu) and found an easy way to beat the purpose.

I'm wondering if I can somehow I can circumvent this:

- Perhaps Tasker could block and unblock Shutdown using Alarmy's actions as triggers;
- Another approach would be to somehow block it via terminal/Termux. The only times I ever need to turn my phone off is during chess tournaments, so I wouldn't mind having to enable Shutdown again and disable it afterwards;
- Maybe this can be done with a Magisk module;
- Or, my last guess, maybe I'll need a custom ROM for that.

And of course, perhaps this is not possible at all. Is it?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How can I prevent myself from powering down my phone while "Alarmy (Sleep If U Can)" is trying to wake me up?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/93535/44325), but it might be outdated

Comment: Definitely related, but I don't think it's a dupe. On Jan 2015, current Android was Lollipop and Magisk wasn't released until 2017.